# spring 2.5 - Move /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml to resources/META-INF

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've recently completed a spring mvc web application deployed as a war file built with maven that looked like this...

```
 >MyApp
    >src
       >main
          >java
          >resources
             >META-INF
                >spring
                   >applicationContext.xml
          >webapp
             >WEB-INF
```

Now I'm trying to create a non-maven spring mvc application and I have this structure working...

```
>MyApp
   >src
   >WebContent
      >WEB-INF
         >applicationContext.xml
```

For this non-maven project I would like to move applicationContext.xml into a better location like I did in my maven project. I spent a lot of time playing around with it this morning but cannot find out how to do it successfully.

Can someone please give me a suggestion of how to best do it? i.e. If there should be a resources folder then where can I put it in my project structure and place the aplpicationContext.xml etc.

In my web.xml the location is specified as ....

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Ideally after the change in location of my applicationContext.xml my web.xml would like similar to this.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am using spring 2.5 because I'm restricted by a very old version on websphere.

thanks

Comment: How do you build your non-maven war?

Comment: The `metainf` subelement of the `war` task should do the trick. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1267352/1686330 replacing `ear` with `war`.