# Ant build.xml ear generation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ant

I have a j2ee application. That application is packaged as ear file. Inside that ear file there are two wars. Can anyone guide me that how I create an ear file consisting those war's inside that ear with ant build.xml script.

Comment: The [ear task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html) documentation is pretty straightforward.  Have you written an Ant build file before?

Answer (score -1):

You can use command line to create EAR using below command:

```
jar -cvf <<ear file name>> <<war files to be included>>
```

You can also refer to question [how to create ear file, and include war and jar files inside that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197114/how-to-create-ear-file-and-include-war-and-jar-files-inside-that).

Also, if you want to do it using build.xml, you can refer [How do I create an EAR file with an ant build including certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267300/how-do-i-create-an-ear-file-with-an-ant-build-including-certain-files)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually i need to generate ear only through ant build

Comment: See the second link which I provided.